# duplicate controllers being created by ng-include directive

Tags: angularjs

I'm using the ngInclude directive and defining my own controller

```
 <ng-include
   src="'app/streaming/streaming.view.html'"
   ng-controller="StreamingCtrl"
   ng-if="streamingActive">
 </ng-include>
```

This is defined within main-page.view.html which is the top level page for my app and is listed in app.js as follows:

```
 app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider.when('/', {
         templateUrl: 'app/common/main-page.view.html',
         controller: 'HomeCtrl', 
         reloadOnSearch:false
     })
     .when('/multiview', {
         templateUrl: 'app/common/main-page.view.html',
         controller: 'MultiviewCtrl'
     })
}]);
```

The streaming control is as follows:

```
 app.controller('StreamingCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     console.log($scope);

      $scope.$on('destroy', function () {
          console.log('destroy');
      });
 }]);
```

Everytime I navigate between the home and multiview pages it looks like a new instance of the controller is being created. The scope is logged and each one has a new id but it seems like the destroy method is never call. I think that this is causing a memory leak with new controller instances being created while the old ones are never destroyed.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated

C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have mispelled the destroy event, it should be `$destroy` instead of `destroy`.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/uWdXQz8w4V6oDCokyYGy?p=preview)**

```
  .controller('StreamCtrl', function($scope) {

    console.log($scope);

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
      console.log('destroy');
    });

  });
```